# how to attach datetime to local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I was trying to convert a date of varchar type(yyyy/mm/dd) to datetime and concatenate to local variable. I get error "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". kindly let me know how could I resolve this. I am using sql 2008 and convert() doesnt' work.

```
set @select = 'select * from tbl t where t.date=''' + cast(replace(@startdate,'/','') as datetime) + ''''
```

when I try to cast date as shown below, it does get concatenated to @select variable but doesn't give the desired output:

```
cast(cast(@startdate as datetime) as varchar(20))
```

Comment: Why does the format matter for a date in your `WHERE` statement?  Are you trying to adjust for column `[date]` not a DATETIME?

Comment: @jr: date is just a column name of datetime

Comment: Right.....   My question was why do you care about what format the date is that you're comparing to?  If both the column and the variable are of the type DATETIME, then the format does not matter for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following to get the desired output:

```
FORMAT([DateColumn],'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

**EDIT :- This won't work for sql server 2008**

This will

```
 REPLACE(Convert(nvarchar(10),[Datecolumn],111),'/','-')
```

Edited to format as yyyy-mm-dd instead of yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: @android: i don't think format() works in sql 2008 as i get format is not a recognized built in function name error

Comment: @user3399326 Edited to include solution for server 2008

Comment: @android: how would I convert eg: varchar( '2000/12/20') to '2000-12-20'. that was what I was trying to do. thnks.